# postgres best practice - queuing table for many consumers

Tags: postgresql

What is the best practice to implement the following in postgres:

- One system puts tasks into a queue, about 5.000 per minute. The tasks carry a payload of varying sizes (a few KB to several MB)
- Several consumers now pick up these tasks. First, they mark a task as taken (in-progress). Then, when the task is done they remove the task from the queue.

The way we are doing it is having a table 'tasks' that has a column 'status' and a column 'payload'. Into this table 5000 tasks are inserted per minute. These 5000 records are then - each individually, as each task is processed individually - updated to status=in-progress. Then, these 5000 records are deleted - again individually - when the tasks are done. We have several indexes on the table, the payload sits in the table (albeit sometimes toasted). We are seeing a very high amount of WALWrite because of this, which makes sense. We do not see disabling synchronous commit as an option.

So I am curious how would such a queuing system optimally look in postgres? Use several tables instead of one? Insert only tables? No indexes (for HOT-updates)? Payload in separate table that is not updated and maybe deleted asynchronously?

Comment: It's a classic use case of one to one relationship to optimize performance on large tables, dividing the less changing of the most changing data or the heavier from the lighter.

Comment: Maybe you can skip the update: start a transaction, delete the task returning the content to your consumer, execute the task, and when successful commit. Otherwise rollback. The avoids the update and should speed up your processes and reduce WAL

Comment: @FrankHeikens interesting idea - I need a 'select for update skip locked' on top of the delete though, am I right? In my head I can't make this work with just deletes.

Comment: @Peter Without any knowledge about your proces, it's hard to judge if something is possible or nor. But when the goal is to delete something from the queue, I would try to delete the record instead of updating it. Using skip locked makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You have tasks and you have a queue - these look like two tables to me. Your task has its id and payload data etc. Your queue has the task id, timestamps, status etc.

If you want some sort of "automagical" synchronisation of this stuff, you can have triggers to queue any new tasks and an ON DELETE foreign key that removes the queue item when the task is deleted.

Comment: There is nothing magical in a standard rule(update/delete) for a foreign key on a relational database.

Comment: It's magical in the same way the trigger is. If you don't know it's there then you'll be surprised (maybe pleasantly, maybe not). In my happy dream-world where things are documented and people read the documents we'd be able to go all day without being surprised of course.